# How to initialize an identity matrix in tensorflow with no specified parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement part of the code on Graph Convolutional Networks given in this [article](https://www.experoinc.com/post/node-classification-by-graph-convolutional-network). I notice that the author uses tf.eye() with no shape parameter. When I tried to rerun the same code, using tensorflow 1, it gave me the expected error that `TypeError: eye() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num_rows'`
Can someone explain how the `tf.eye()` in the article works and/or if there was another way to initialize an identity matrix with unspecified shape?
Here is the code (compatible with tensorflow 1 coz apprently tensorflow2 doesn't have `tf.placeolder()`)

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import tensorflow as tf
features=  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
adjacency=  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
degree=  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
labels=  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
weights= tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([], 0, 1, tf.float32, seed=1))
def layer(features, adjacency, degree, weights):
    with tf.name_scope('gcn_layer'):
        d_ =tf.pow(degree + tf.eye(), -0.5)
        y = tf.matmul(d_, tf.matmul(adjacency, d_))
        kernel = tf.matmul(features, weights)
        
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y,kernel))
    
model = layer(features, adjacency, degree, weights)    
    
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        loss =tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.somftmax_crosse_ntropy_with_logits(
                                logits=model, labels=labels))
        train_op=train.AdamOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(loss)
        
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
        features:features, adjacency:adjacency, degree:degree, labels:labels})
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.eye()` is used to create a identity matrix.
The correct usage of `tf.eye()` is:
**Code:**

```
tf.eye(
    num_rows, num_columns=None, batch_shape=None, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None
)
```

`num_rows` is the number of rows for your identity matrix. So If you want to create an identity matrix of `shape : (2,2)` you have to specify `num_rows = 2`

**Example Usage:**

```
tf.eye(2)

==> [[1., 0.],
     [0., 1.]]
```

Comment: What if you want to add an identity matrix with no specified parameter. For example, If you want to define a function that adds an identity matrix that matched the shape of the input (where input has only placeholder and could be of any shape)?